# How to use secret task variables with npm tasks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-tasks

I've defined `Variable Group` which downloads `secrets` from `Key Vault`.
Looks like that unlike other variables, secrets aren't set automatically as environment variables.
I've tried using a bash script to take those 'task variables' and set them as environment variables but they were gone by the next task:

```
export ENV1=$(someSecretTaskVariable)
```

I'm using `npm` task which can't be provided with environment variables via the UI and the yaml is read only.

How should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an environment variable that is passed to subsequent Azure DevOps tasks, maybe try this :

`echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=ENV1]$(someSecretTaskVariable)'`

instead of `export ENV1=$(someSecretTaskVariable)`

[Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-in-script)

Comment: Not the best experience but will definitely do the trick in this case. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I dont think you can do this via UI</strike>, but via yaml you would do this:

```
- task: xxx
  env:
    ENV1=$(someSecretTaskVariable)
```

apparently you can do this:

> Unlike a normal variable, they are not automatically decrypted into
>   environment variables for scripts. You can explicitly map them in,
>   though.
>
> To pass a secret to a script, use the Environment section of the
>   scripting task's input variables.

seems like with UI you can only do this with scripting tasks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#secret-variables

Comment: How can I edit the `yaml`? I see only 'View YAML' button which only shows the yaml with no ability to edit it

Comment: you need to create a pipeline as a yaml pipeline, not visual pipeline

Comment: unfortunately `npm` task doesn't have Environment section, so I guess that leaves us with yaml pipeline, that's too bad :(

Comment: yaml is really much better when you get used to it

Comment: this pipeline will be shared with other people as well, I prefer to stick with the known rather than getting everybody to know a new format

Comment: well, thats why we are not using clubs and stone axes there days.

Comment: That's the first feature missing from the 'UI' vs the yaml, I'm not sure your comparison is relevant here,,

Comment: its not only about features missing, its about scalability\control\reuse\etc